# Logic for Date Selection

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I am stuck in writing this logic in R. Can someone help me to write this logic?

Logic:

> > (Priority1) For an Item, Date1 == Calendar then we have to select that row. Eg - Item B

> > (Priority2) For an Item if not Priority1 then, Date1 ~ Previous date in Calendar column then select that row. Eg - Item C

> > (Priority3) For an Item if not Priority1 & 2 then, Date1 ~ Next date in Calendar column then select that row. Eg - Item A

Input:

```
Item   Date1     Calendar
A   2021-01-08  2021-01-11
A   2021-01-08  2021-01-19
B   2021-02-05  2021-01-29
B   2021-02-05  2021-02-05
B   2021-02-05  2021-02-12
C   2021-02-15  2021-02-07
C   2021-02-15  2021-02-13
C   2021-02-15  2021-02-20
C   2021-02-15  2021-02-27
```

This is the `dput` of the data

```
input <- structure(list(Item = c("A", "A", "B", "B","B", "C", "C","C","C"), Date1 = c("2021-01-08", 
                                                            "2021-01-08", "2021-02-05", "2021-02-05", "2021-02-05", "2021-02-15", "2021-02-15", "2021-02-15", "2021-02-15"), Calendar = c("2021-01-11", "2021-01-19", "2021-01-29", "2021-02-05","2021-02-12", "2021-02-07","2021-02-13", "2021-02-20", "2021-02-27")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Output:

```
Item   Date1     Calendar
A   2021-01-08  2021-01-11
B   2021-02-05  2021-02-05
C   2021-02-15  2021-02-13
```

This is the `dput` of the expected output.

```
output <- structure(list(Item = c("A","B", "C"), Date1 = c("2021-01-08","2021-02-05", "2021-02-15"), Calendar = c("2021-01-11","2021-02-05","2021-02-13")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another `tidyverse` approach. Calculate the absolute difference between `Date1` and `Calendar`. Then, assign priority values based on rules described above (for priorities 1, 2, or 3). Then, sort based on priority, and the difference in days. Finally, for each group take the first row (highest priority, based on rules and closest date).

```
library(tidyverse)

input$Date1 <- as.Date(input$Date1)
input$Calendar <- as.Date(input$Calendar)

input %>%
  mutate(Diff = abs(Date1 - Calendar)) %>%
  group_by(Item) %>%
  mutate(Priority = case_when(
    Diff == 0 ~ 1,
    Date1 > Calendar ~ 2,
    TRUE ~ 3
  )) %>%
  arrange(Priority, Diff) %>%
  slice(1)
```

**Output**

```
  Item  Date1      Calendar   Diff   Priority
  <chr> <date>     <date>     <drtn>    <dbl>
1 A     2021-01-08 2021-01-11 3 days        3
2 B     2021-02-05 2021-02-05 0 days        1
3 C     2021-02-15 2021-02-13 2 days        2
```

Comment: Apologies.. It doesn't have to be the closest it has to be the previous & next date for P2 & P3. Made respective changes in the requirement.

Comment: @AnshulSaravgi Could you give an example to demonstrate the difference? If your `Calendar` column is sorted by date, shouldn't the result be the same? If they are not sorted, you can add `arrange` in the pipe to sort.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper function that uses `case_when` for your logic.

The data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
input <- structure(list(Item = c("A", "A", "B", "B","B", "C", "C","C","C"),
                        Date1 = c("2021-01-08", "2021-01-08", "2021-02-05", "2021-02-05", "2021-02-05", "2021-02-15", "2021-02-15", "2021-02-15", "2021-02-15"),
                        Calendar = c("2021-01-11", "2021-01-19", "2021-01-29", "2021-02-05","2021-02-12", "2021-02-07","2021-02-13", "2021-02-20", "2021-02-27")),
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

The rules:

```
# rules are
# 1) get the equal
# 2) get the closest previous
# 3) get the closest next
```

Modifying things

```
# make things dates
input %>% 
  mutate(Date1 = as_date(Date1),
         Calendar = as_date(Calendar)) -> input
```

This is the helper function you can use.

```
find_proper_row <- function(x){
  case_when(any(x == 0) ~ x == 0,
            any(x < 0) ~ x == max(x[which(x<0)]),
            # if all positive, get the min
            all(x > 0) ~ x == min(x[which(x>0)]))
}

# try it out
> find_proper_row(c(0, 10, -10, 11))
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> find_proper_row(c(20, 10, -10, 11))
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> find_proper_row(c(20, 10, 10, 11))
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

As you can see, ties might be a problem here, you didn't specify a rule for ties, but you can probably update the logic at the end of the function such that only one `TRUE` is returned on the `logical` vector.

Now let's calculate a difference in days on the `input` by group.

```
input %>% 
  mutate(diff = as.numeric(Calendar - Date1)) %>% 
  group_by(Item) %>%
  mutate(keep = find_proper_row(diff)) -> input


# Now you can filter them 
input %>%
  filter(keep)
# select(-diff, - keep) for proper output
```

Which produces

```
  Item  Date1      Calendar    diff keep 
  <chr> <date>     <date>     <dbl> <lgl>
1 A     2021-01-08 2021-01-11     3 TRUE 
2 B     2021-02-05 2021-02-05     0 TRUE 
3 C     2021-02-15 2021-02-13    -2 TRUE
```

Comment: Matias - Apologies.. It doesn't have to be the closest it has to be the previous & next date for P2 & P3. Made respective changes in the requirement.